# Properties in a base class not appearing in view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a base class which looks a little like this:

```
public class EformBase
{
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Longitude {get;set;}
    // lots of other properties here
}
```

and a derived class which looks like this:

```
public class GraffitiViewModel : EformBase
{
    public RadioButtonList<YesNoType> GraffitiOffensive { get; set; }
    public RadioButtonList<YesNoType> GraffitiTag { get; set; }
    // other properties here
}
```

I am using this class as a view model in MVC. Unfortunately, when the view model is posted back, the properties in the base class are not appearing in the view model. Like  this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(GraffitiViewModel vm)
{
   // add to database code
}
```

The vm, when posted back to this action, does not include the longitude and latitude as specified in the base class. What am I missing? Do I have to do something special for the base class to be included?

Comment: can you provide view markup?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, your post does not mention if you are (or not) using the two properties (Latitude and Longitude) inside your View.

In addition, when you mention:
*Unfortunately, when the view model is posted back, the properties in the base class are not appearing in the view model.*

> Do you mean that you do NOT see the two properties?
>
> OR
>
> Do you mean that you see the two properties but the values are null?

Consider the following code example:

**ViewModel and Base class:**

```
public class MyViewModel : MyBaseViewModel
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
}

public class MyBaseViewModel
{
    public string Z { get; set; }
}
```

**The Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel myViewModel)
    {
        var z = myViewModel.Z;
        return null;
    }
}
```

**The View:**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>MyViewModel</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.A)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.A)</div>

        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.B)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.B)</div>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Notice how the view only is only using property A and property B.

When I submit the `<form>` and place a breakpoint on my [HttpPost] method inside my Controller, I can view the values I entered for the textbox A and textbox B.

But since I do not have a textbox C and a textbox D. These properties will be set to null.

Likewise for property Z which happens to be defined in my Base class.

Because property Z is not used in my `<form>`, when I submit it, I’ll have null as a value.

In order to view property Z when you submit the `<form>`, you’d have to add it inside your `<form>...</form>` like so:

```
<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Z)</div>
<div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Z)</div>
```